# WPF: Link from grid to form

Tags: wpf, grid

What I need is a grid with all employees data, and a link to a single employees form.
I'm ok with filling the grid with data. my questions are:
how to create the link?
how to send the parameter (employeeid) to the single-employee page, and make it open with the correct data.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to parameterized the constructor of your form that shows single employee records like:

```
public PageName(int employeeid)
{
    //do your stuff here.. like retrieving to the database the records of the given employeeid and setting the control values, etc.
}
```

When you create an instance of that form all you need to do is to provide a employeeid of the selected record on the list like:

```
PageName x = new PageName(value for employeeid);
```

Comment: thanks. that works.
have any clue about how to do that from a grid?

Comment: You just need to code on the grid's event like mousedoubleclick, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx), it will help. You can use it as a pattern

Comment: that is a very interesting page, i have learned a lot from it.
but I did not see there how to open a page from a grid with a param.
am I missing something? I'm sure it's possible.